# How do I distribute ASP.NET MVC View as a NuGet Package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I have an ASP.NET MVC View that I use for configuration that I like. I can access that view by navigating to `/super-config`. I would like to be able to reuse that view across my ASP.NET MVC apps. Ideally, I would like to be able to distribute the view as a NuGet package. Then, if I add the NuGet package to a new ASP.NET MVC app, I could then navigate to `/super-config` in the ASP.NET MVC app and it would work.

Is there a way to do this in ASP.NET MVC? If so, how?

Comment: "if I add the NuGet package to a new ASP.NET MVC app, I could then navigate to /super-config in the ASP.NET MVC app and it would work." ...yes you can. I've done something similar. In the package you need to distribute both the view, and a controller containing the action which would allow the user to navigate to it.

Comment: @ADyson - What's in the package though? An assembly with the Controller and View? If I import a package, it seems like I would need to connect it to the new ASP.NET MVC app somehow. That's the piece I don't get. How does the new ASP.NET MVC app know to route to the controller?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work in this scenario. You put the cshtml file in there directly in the "content" section of the package. And also in the "content" you put a file with the extension `.cs.pp` - this is the controller file (obviously put each of these in the appropriate subfolder within the content section so they go into the right place in the target project). Then when you install the package, the .pp file then gets transformed suitably into a .cs file and will (if you add the right variables) adopt the correct namespace etc of the target project, so it's as if you added it manually.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations for more info on the .pp file concept

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Core docs have a page titled [Share controllers, views, Razor Pages and more with Application Parts in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.0). They have this code snippet:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Requires using System.Reflection;
    // Requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts;
    var assembly = typeof(MySharedController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var part = new AssemblyPart(assembly);
    services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part))
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

It's been years since I used the .NET Framework version of ASP.NET MVC and no longer remember how to do it. <strike>Searching for two minutes I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. There should be an API where you tell MVC which additional assemblies to search for MVC controllers. But I found [this blog post](http://rion.io/2016/06/27/extending-mvc-controllers-from-external-assemblies-and-projects/) which might help.</strike> Of course seconds after I posted this answer, I found a blog post with the info I was looking for immediately below the link to the other blog post I linked. Anyway, [this blog post](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-controllers-from-an-external-assembly-in-asp-net-web-api/) shows how to do it, although I don't recommend at all using `Assembly.Load`. Use `typeof(MyController).Assembly` instead.